# Calling Gstreamer inside openCV

Tags: c++, c, opencv, ubuntu, gstreamer

I need to call Gstremaer inside an openCV code (opening a video camera essentially).
As I looked through the source code, `modules/highgui/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp` seems to be the file I'm looking for.

I compiled OpenCV with Gstreamer flag.

```
 GStreamer:
--       base:                      YES (ver 1.2.3)
--       video:                     YES (ver 1.2.3)
--       app:                       YES (ver 1.2.3)
--       riff:                      YES (ver 1.2.3)
--       pbutils:                   YES (ver 1.2.3)
```

but I'm not able to call a Gstreamer-related functions (e.g. `cvCreateCapture_GStreamer` which is defined inside `cap_gstreamer.cpp`)
`cap_gstreamer.cpp` was built successfully as the opencv install log suggested:

```
[ 17%] Building CXX object modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp.o
```

`cvCreateCapture_GStreamer` is also present inside `/usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.3.0.0` after building openCV
(found that using `grep`)

I use `#include <opencv/highgui.h>` but calling `cvCreateCapture_GStreamer`fails(`-lopencv_highgui` flag is set inside the Makefile):

```
error: ‘cvCapture_GStreamer’ was not declared in this scope
```

Any suggestions would be helpful and greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: cvCapture_GStreamer is not part of the public (client) api. it's used internally in the highgui module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, **you can't use GStreamer API through OpenCV**. What OpenCV has is a series of wrapper functions (as, for instance, `cvCaptureFromCam`) which implement their functionalities through external multimedia libraries. For instance, aside from GStreamer, OpenCV might use other libraries such as ffmpeg, v4l.. in fact, if you check the complete list of files related with multimedia capture through different external libraries you will find:

```
(in opencv/modules/highgui/src)
cap_cmu.cpp    
cap_dc1394.cpp    
cap_ffmpeg.cpp    
cap_gstreamer.cpp
...
```

So, if you compile OpenCV with GStreamer support, you will call the same highgui functions (as `cvCaptureFromCam`) but, at a low level it will be calling functions like `cvCreateCapture_GStreamer` which implement the calls to the GStreamer API. But it does not mean that you can call yourself to those low-level functions (hence the "was not declared in this scope" error).

Hope that it helps!

EDITED: 
take a look to the [cap.cpp](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/highgui/src/cap.cpp#L206) file in the opencv source. Notice the different options for `CvCreateCameraCapture_XXX`. It makes me think that you should be able to open your camera without some of the dependencies (by using others instead).

Comment: That's a great explanation, Thanks! So, by default (e.g. compiling OpenCV with no GStreamer support), how does it (opening the camera) work? 
Reason I'm asking is I have a custom board which uses other driver than v4l/v4l2, which I can open the camera using gstreamer, but obviously no luck trying to use OpenCV. Is there any way to change the low level OpenCV function to use other drivers?

Comment: I edited my answer, though I have no deeper knowledge of how the highgui dependencies work at a lower level. You might ask another question like "Installing OpenCV in <yourBoard>" or further search in the OpenCV documentation..